# Django - Celery ValueError: Related model u'user.User' cannot be resolved

Tags: python, django, django-models, celery, django-celery

When I am executing celery task it is giving me:

**ValueError: Related model u'user.User' cannot be resolved**

The stacktrace is

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/prince/virtualenvs/set/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 375, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/prince/virtualenvs/set/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 632, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/prince/work/magneto/set/facebook_pages/tasks.py", line 23, in analyze_page
    connected_facebook_page = get_connected_facebook_page(connected_facebook_page_id)
  File "/Users/prince/work/magneto/set/facebook_pages/utils.py", line 49, in get_connected_facebook_page
    return ConnectedUserPage.objects.get(id=connected_facebook_page_id)
  File "/Users/prince/virtualenvs/set/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/prince/virtualenvs/set/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 374, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/Users/prince/virtualenvs/set/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 232, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/prince/virtualenvs/set/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1118, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/prince/virtualenvs/set/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "/Users/prince/virtualenvs/set/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 876, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/Users/prince/virtualenvs/set/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 428, in as_sql
    extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
  File "/Users/prince/virtualenvs/set/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 46, in pre_sql_setup
    self.setup_query()
  File "/Users/prince/virtualenvs/set/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 37, in setup_query
    self.select, self.klass_info, self.annotation_col_map = self.get_select()
  File "/Users/prince/virtualenvs/set/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 194, in get_select
    for c in self.get_default_columns():
  File "/Users/prince/virtualenvs/set/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 569, in get_default_columns
    column = field.get_col(alias)
  File "/Users/prince/virtualenvs/set/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1008, in get_col
    return super(ForeignKey, self).get_col(alias, output_field or self.target_field)
  File "/Users/prince/virtualenvs/set/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 909, in target_field
    return self.foreign_related_fields[0]
  File "/Users/prince/virtualenvs/set/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 653, in foreign_related_fields
    return tuple(rhs_field for lhs_field, rhs_field in self.related_fields if rhs_field)
  File "/Users/prince/virtualenvs/set/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 640, in related_fields
    self._related_fields = self.resolve_related_fields()
  File "/Users/prince/virtualenvs/set/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 625, in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
ValueError: Related model u'user.User' cannot be resolved
```

Here ConnectedUserPage is a model with schema:

```
class ConnectedUserPage(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey('user.User', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    page = models.ForeignKey(FacebookPage, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    page_details = jsonb.JSONField()
```

My versions are :

```
celery==4.1.1
django-celery-beat==1.1.1
django-celery-results==1.0.1
Django==1.11.13
```

In case I directly import User model from user app I am getting stuck in circular imports.

Any help would be appreciated, stuck in this loop for a quite while now.

Answer (score 0):

Where's `User` defined? Is this Django's own user model? If that's the case you can use User model directly:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class ConnectedUserPage(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

or you can also do

```
from django.conf import settings

class ConnectedUserPage(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

If it is your own supplied User model, are you sure `user` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`?